# C++ - Problemas con entrada de variable Char

Tags: c++, struct

Estoy intentando grabar una serie de datos en un struct en c++. Sin embargo tengo el problema que el campo "polizaActiva" (Qué debería tener sólo V y F) no toma los valores que quiero: Guarda los del campo subsiguiente. Creo que es un problema relacionado con como captar valores Char. Pero estuve buscando en [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) y no pude encontrar nada que me haya hecho entender.

Este es el struct:

```
struct poliza{
    int nroPoliza;
    char dniAsegurado[11];
    char nombreAsegurado[50];
    char apellidoAsegurado[50];
    char cuotaAlDia[1];
    char patenteAuto[10];
    char polizaActiva[1];
    int cantIncidentes;
};
```

Con este método lo cargo

```
bool cargarNuevaPoliza(void){
    FILE *f;
    poliza p;
    if(f=fopen(ARCHIVOASEGURADOS, "a"))
    {
        cout << "Ingrese Numero de Poliza:" << endl;
        cin >> p.nroPoliza;
        cout << "Ingrese DNI:" << endl;
        cin >> p.dniAsegurado;
        cout << "Ingrese Nombre:" << endl;
        cin >> p.nombreAsegurado;
        cout << "Ingrese Apellido:" << endl;
        cin >> p.apellidoAsegurado;
        cout << "Posee la cuota al dia (V/F):" << endl;
        cin >> p.cuotaAlDia;
        cout << "Ingrese patente del auto:" << endl;
        cin >> p.patenteAuto;
        cout << "Poliza activa (V/F):" << endl;
        cin >> p.polizaActiva;
        cout << "Ingrese cantidad de Incidentes:" << endl;
        cin >> p.cantIncidentes;
        fwrite(&p, sizeof(poliza),1, f);
        fclose(f);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Con este los leo:

```
void levantarAsegurados()
{
    FILE*F;
    int i = 0;
    poliza V [1000];
    F = fopen(ARCHIVOASEGURADOS,"rb");
    fseek(F,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&V[i],sizeof(poliza),1,F);
    while (!feof(F))
    {
        cout << V[i].nroPoliza << endl;
        cout << V[i].dniAsegurado << endl;
        cout << V[i].nombreAsegurado << endl;
        cout << V[i].apellidoAsegurado << endl;
        cout << V[i].cuotaAlDia << endl;
        cout << V[i].patenteAuto << endl;
        cout << V[i].polizaActiva << endl;
        cout << V[i].cantIncidentes << endl;
        i++;
        fread(&V[i],sizeof(poliza),1,F);
    }
    fclose(F);
}
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e05UD.jpg)

Comment: No veo la variable "Patente Activa"

Comment: @jqc Creo que se refiere a **polizaActiva**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poner esto:

```
char polizaActiva[1];
```

Mejor lo dejas así:

```
char polizaActiva;
```

Más sencillo, claro y fácil de entender. Piensa que las cadenas de texto necesitan al menos dos caracteres (uno para almacenar un caracter y otro para finalizar la cadena).

Más que nada porque luego haces:

```
cin >> p.polizaActiva;
```

Y supuestamente, `cin` finaliza las cadenas de texto... ¿Cómo se supone que debe finalizar esta? Ya te lo digo yo... pisando memoria que no pertenece al array. Sin embargo si dejas la variable como un simple `char`, `cin` no tratará la variable como una cadena y no intentará finalizar la misma.

Porque claro, luego haces:

```
cout << V[i].polizaActiva << endl;
```

Y `cout`, como se encuentra con un array de caracteres empieza a sacar valores hasta que se encuentra con un caracter nulo... que no va a estar donde tu esperas... el finalizador de cadena que ha puesto `cin` ya no se encuentra ahí porque, presumiblemente, ha sido pisado por operaciones posteriores.

Si esto último no te cuadra vamos a ver un posible ejemplo de uso:

Memoria inicial (no hay nada inicializado):

```
| polActiva |  cantIncidentes   | otras variables ... |
|           |    |    |    |    |    [basura]         |
```

operación:

```
cin >> p.polizaActiva; // supongamos que se introduce 'V'
```

estado de la memoria:

```
| polActiva |  cantIncidentes   | otras variables ... |
|     V     | \0 |    |    |    |    [basura]         |
```

operación:

```
cin >> p.cantIncidentes;
```

estado de la memoria (ejemplo hipotético porque depende también de si la máquina es big-endian o little-endian... entre otras cosas:

```
| polActiva |  cantIncidentes   | otras variables ... |
|     V     | 01 | 0A | 00 | 00 |    [basura]         |
```

Si ahora haces:

```
cout << p.polizaActiva
```

La función empezará a recorrer bytes e irá imprimiéndolos hasta que se encuentre un '\0'... y como ves el finalizador de cadena que tenías inicialmente se ha perdido.

La estructura debería lucir así:

```
struct poliza{
    int nroPoliza;
    char dniAsegurado[11];
    char nombreAsegurado[50];
    char apellidoAsegurado[50];
    char cuotaAlDia;
    char patenteAuto[10];
    char polizaActiva;
    int cantIncidentes;
};
```

Aunque teniendo en cuenta que estás en C++ lo mejor sería dejarla así:

```
struct poliza{
    int nroPoliza;
    std::string dniAsegurado;
    std::string nombreAsegurado;
    std::string apellidoAsegurado;
    char cuotaAlDia;
    std::string patenteAuto;
    char polizaActiva;
    int cantIncidentes;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sustituye  ***char cuotaAlDia[1];*** por ***char cuotaAlDia;*** y 
           ***char polizaActiva[1];*** por ***char polizaActiva;***. Es decir, elimina la declaración del array.  ¿No te da error en **F = fopen(ARCHIVOASEGURADOS,"rb");**?, debería por que *ARCHIVOASEGURADOS* no está entre comillas

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser un define: `#define ARCHIVOASEGURADOS "abcdef.txt"`